# Does Swift let me forward a property to another class?

Tags: ios, swift, properties, callback

I often have the need for a class to forward a property to another class, like:

```
  var thumbnailTappedCallback: (Photo) -> Void {
    get {
      return controlBar.thumbnailTappedCallback
    }
    set {
      controlBar.thumbnailTappedCallback = newValue
    }
  }
```

Does Swift offer a better to do this, by forwarding a property from one class to another, like:

```
var thumbnailTappedCallback = forward(controlBar.thumbnailTappedCallback)
```

The background is that each view in the view hierarchy exposes such callbacks. Parent views aggregate and vend the views up the hierarchy. Child views are only an implementation detail of the parent views, and are not accessed directly. Some are even fileprivate. But this means that higher-level classes have as many as four such callbacks that forward to other classes.

I wanted to check if there's a cleaner solution to this problem.

Comment: If your code works and you are asking if a better solution exists, I think you have the wrong forum. You are looking for the Code Review forum: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The question was whether Swift lets me forward a property to another class. I updated the question with an example of how that could work. I'm not asking for a code review :)

Comment: I'm thinking iOS (not just Swift) doesn't offer this, unless you wish to pass back an entire class instance. You can always use the *tag* property (which is an Int value) or *expose* a property publicly (which combined with a tag setting would kludge your way to something) but I'm pretty sure those won't cut it for you. Maybe somebody else has a better way?